# An operation where it is closed under the operation but is not a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is the question:

Give an example of a group $G$ (Where you need to specify the operation) together with a non-empty subset $H$ of $G$ that is closed under the operation of $G$ but that is not a subgroup.

If I'm understanding correctly. I need to provide the operation $G$ where a non-empty subset $H \subseteq G$ that is closed under $G$ but is not a subgroup... But if it is closed under $G$, shouldn't it be a subgroup as well?

Comment: "But if it is closed under G, shouldn't it be a subgroup as well? " Not if the identity isn't included and/or not every element has an inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $G =\mathbb R$ under addition. $H=(0, \infty)$ is closed under addition but it is not a subgroup since it doesn't have an identity element..

Answer (score 2):

Take $G = \Bbb Z$ and $H = \Bbb N$.